2014 Toyota tacoma has no throttle after jump start
My truck died I jumped it and got it started again now the check engine light and the TRAC off light are on and I have no throttle. It starts and rolls but when I push on the pedal there's nothing. I tested the battery and it's all good as well as the fuses. I haven't got my hands on a code reader yet but I plan to.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I figured it out etcs fuse was blown

Make that an answer.
